# Manual object lifetime with ARC

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

Examine the following code, and assume it was compiled under ARC:

```
- (void)foo {
    NSOperationQueue *oq = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [oq addOperationWithBlock:^{
        // Pretend that we have a long-running operation here.
    }];
}
```

Although the operation queue is declared as a local variable, its lifetime continues beyond the scope of the method as long as it has running operations.

How is this achieved?

**UPDATE:**

I appreciate Rob Mayoff's well-thought-out comments, but I think I did not ask my question correctly. I am not asking a specific question about NSOperationQueue, but rather a general question about object lifetime in ARC. Specifically, my question is this:

*How, under ARC, can an object participate in the management of its own lifetime?*

I've been a programmer for a very long time, and I'm well aware of the pitfalls of such a thing. I am not looking to be lectured as to whether this is a good or bad idea. I think in general it is a bad one. Rather, my question is academic: *Whether it's a good or bad idea or not, how would one do this in ARC and what is the specific syntax to do so?*

Comment: I thought this was an interesting question before, and the update is as good if not better. Maybe, since you've already got a good answer to what the question seemed to be earlier, you should just post the more general version as its own question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a general case you can keep a reference to yourself. E.g.:

```
@implementation MasterOfMyOwnDestiny
{
   MasterOfMyOwnDestiny *alsoMe;
}

- (void) lifeIsGood
{
    alsoMe = self;
}

- (void) woeIsMe
{
    alsoMe = nil;
}

...

@end
```

Comment: Love those class and method names!

Comment: Interestingly, when I tried this, I did not get a compiler warning about a cycle.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few possibilities:

1. The `NSOperationQueue` retains itself until it is empty, then releases itself.
2. The `NSOperationQueue` causes some other object to retain it.  For example, since `NSOperationQueue` uses GCD, perhaps `addOperationWithBlock:` looks something like this:

   ```
   - (void)addOperationWithBlock:(void (^)(void))block {
       void (^wrapperBlock)(void) = ^{
           block();
           [self executeNextBlock];
       };
       if (self.isCurrentlyExecuting) {
           [self.queuedBlocks addObject:wrapperBlock];
       } else {
           self.isCurrentlyExecuting = YES;
           dispatch_async(self.dispatchQueue, wrapperBlock);
       }
   }
   ```

   In that code, the `wrapperBlock` contains a strong reference to the `NSOperationQueue`, so (assuming ARC), it retains the `NSOperationQueue`.  (The real `addOperationWithBlock:` is more complex than this, because it is thread-safe and supports executing multiple blocks concurrently.)
3. The `NSOperationQueue` *doesn't* live past the scope of your `foo` method.  Maybe by the time `addOperationWithBlock:` returns, your long-running block has already been submitted to a GCD queue.  Since you don't keep a strong reference to `oq`, there is no reason why `oq` *shouldn't* be deallocated.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, Rob, but it is not exactly what I was looking for. Please read my updated question. Basically, I'm looking for the ARC syntax to implement Choice 1, the object retaining itself. Since I cannot call retain in ARC, how would I do this? Is there some special syntax or do I just have a strong reference cycle that I break by assigning to nil at the appropriate time, suppressing the compiler warning using `clang diagnostic`?

Comment: CRD's answer describes what I do when I need this behavior: use a strong self-referencing ivar.  Set it to nil when the object no longer needs to keep itself alive.

Answer (score 0):

In the example code give, under ARC, the NSOperationQueue, being local to the enclosing lexical scope of the block, is captured is captured by the block.  Basically, the block saves the value of the pointer so it can be accessed from within the block later.  This actually happens regardless of whether you're using ARC or not; the difference is that under ARC, object variables are automatically retained and released as the block is copied and released.

The section ["Object and Block Variables"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW3) in the [Blocks Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html) guide is a good reference for this stuff.

Comment: This is only the case if the pointer to the queue is used _inside_ the Block. They don't just scoop up all the variables in their enclosing scope, only the ones that are actually used.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing I can think of would be to have a global NSMutableArray (or set, or whatever) that the object adds itself to and removes itself from. Another idea would be to put the (as you've already admitted) oddly-memory-managed code in a category in a non-ARC file and just use -retain and -release directly.