# is this a retain cycle in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks

I've declared a property on my UICollectionViewCell like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void(^onSelection)(BOOL selected);
```

I override `-setSelected:` like this:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected {
    [super setSelected:selected];

    if (self.onSelection != NULL) {
        self.onSelection(selected);
    }
}
```

Then in `-cellForItemAtIndexPath:` i configure like this

```
cell.onSelection = ^(BOOL selected) {
    //the compiler is telling me this might be a retain cycle but i dont think so...
    cell.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
};
```

Is this a retain cycle?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is. Instead you should use a weak+strong combo.

```
__weak typeof(cell) weakCell = cell;
cell.onSelection = ^(BOOL selected) {
    __strong typeof(weakCell) strongCell = weakCell;
    //the compiler is telling me this might be a retain cycle but i dont think so...
    strongCell.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
};
```

In your particular case you don't even need this block because you can update cell in subclass inside of `setSelected:` or handle `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` in your table view controller.

Comment: You're right about the delegate methods. I'm more curious about this particular case... My reasoning was this: A retain cycle occurs when two objects maintain strong references to one another. In this particular example, cell can't maintain a strong reference to itself... can it?

Comment: The problem here is cell keeps strong reference to block and block keeps the strong reference to cell. They will never release each other until you explicitly say `cell.onSelection = nil;`.

Comment: You're totally right, when two objects retain each other, there is simply no way to break this cycle until explicitly released. A food for thoughts: The typical cycle people stumble upon is `NSTimer` that does not break the cycle until `invalidate` called, therefore calling `invalidate` in `dealloc` seems impossible since `dealloc` will never be called.

Comment: @SeanDanzeiser - FYI an object can maintain a strong reference to itself, it can do this to keep itself alive, see [Manual Object Lifetime with ARC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489995/manual-object-lifetime-with-arc/10490861#10490861)

Comment: The `strongCell` is unnecessary here, because 1) it's used in only one place, which is no different from using a weak reference in only one place, and 2) all operations on a UI cell are necessarily from the main thread, so it cannot be deallocated in the middle of the block.

Comment: @newacct  There is no such thing as used in one place in programming. Yes, most likely the cell will be around for the whole lifetime of table view, it's more like a general approach I described here.

Comment: @Andy: Whether it's used only once in the scope is relevant; when a weak variable is used more than once in a scope, it could create the unexpected result that it's non-`nil` the first time, and `nil` later; and there is a warning in Xcode about using a weak variable multiple times in a local scope. However, this is not a concern if it is only used once.

Comment: It's not relevant because you roll the dice anyway. Consider block that has heavy computation before it calls weakCell. So if you would create a strong ref in the first place you would get more chances to actually capture object before it's dead. More than one access to weak variable just increases your chances to run into inconsistency.

Comment: But you are right that in this synthetic case, single weak ref would suffice.