# In ARC how does a child object tells parent object I am done, please release me (to avoid memory leaks)

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

My parent object creates a child object to do some async action. It involves some user interaction and that's one of the reasons I didn't use `NSOperation`. Only the child object knows when it has finished its task, then how does it tell its parent object that I am done, please release me to avoid memory leaks?

Currently, I come up with this, the parent object has a callback method called `releaseChild`, which is just `child = nil`; When the child object finishes its task it calls parent's `releaseChild` just to set itself to nil. Actually, I wrap the call in a `dispatch_after` but the idea is the same, the child object calls its parent to set itself to nil.

I was wondering is there a better way ?

----- update -----

I know the "normal" way to write my child is to create a `UIViewController` object, push it to `UINavigationController`. When it is finished user can pop it up, `ARC` will then release it. In that way, I don't need to worry about memory leaks (normally). But I think the question to release a child object when it is done and only it knows when it is done has a border application than writing a `UIViewController` object.

Comment: may i know what type of child class is ???

Comment: Just a "normal" cocoa object with UI & network stuff

Comment: so for that you need to override `dealloc()` method in `child` and call that method with `child` object from `parent` and do stuff what ever you want there to `release`.

Comment: Man, you don't get my question. Don't just answer it for the sake of answering

Comment: Yes I have read your question properly and here I am not just for sake of answering but for help developers and have you try above provided solution ? without try how can you say that its not for your question ?

Comment: @Dhanesh Overwriting `-dealloc` doesn't help, because `dealloc` is never sent to the object: The parent holds it.

Comment: @Amin Negm-Awad besides that, I said ARC, so you can't call dealloc directly and when I set child = nil and when its reference count reaches 0, dealloc will be called by ARC. That's why I said he didn't get my question at all.

Comment: I agree with you. But he did not say to call dealloc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the question:

> Only the child object knows when it has finished its task, then how does it tell its parent object that I am done, please release me to avoid memory leaks?

and in a later comment:

> the problem is the child object can't set itself to nil.

What it appears you need is a child object which controls its own lifetime. This is easily done; an object remains alive as long as there is a reference to it stored in a variable attributed as asserting strong ownership over references stored in it - and that attribute is the default for variable declarations. That variable can be global, local, instance, it doesn't matter... So to control your its own destiny an object just needs to keep a reference to itself.

The following code, copied from [Manual object lifetime with ARC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489995/manual-object-lifetime-with-arc/10490861#10490861) (a previous answer I wrote a few years ago, I can crib from myself ;-)), shows one way to do this:

```
@implementation MasterOfMyOwnDestiny
{
   MasterOfMyOwnDestiny *alsoMe;
}

- (void) lifeIsGood
{
    alsoMe = self;
}

- (void) woeIsMe
{
    alsoMe = nil;
}

...

@end
```

In your case you can have the child set `alsoMe` during its initialisation, so the child starts off controlling its own lifetime. When the child decides it has finished its work it simply calls `[self woeIsMe]` as its *final* action.

Note: You can of course remove the methods and just set the instance variable directly within the child, making it hard for any other object to kill the child off.

If the parent needs to have a reference to the child for any reason, other than to keep the child alive, then it can store that reference in a variable attributed as asserting weak ownership of references stored in it, e.g. something like:

```
__weak MasterOfMyOwnDestiny *myChild = [MasterOfMyOwnDestiny new];
```

such a reference will not keep the object referenced by `myChild` alive, and will be automatically set to `nil` when that object dies.

Comment: Tell me something I didn't know. Thanks! I marked your answer as the accepted one although @nasher729 answer works either. :D

Answer (score 1):

Couple of possible solutions

1) Use protocol-delegation method to let child tell parent that its done (i am assuming thats what you are doing)

2) you can pass variable into the child and which gets set by child once its finishes execution and parent can periodically check its value and clear the child (not a big fan, but kind of polling method), Can be done with created background task or can be added to low priority queue.

3) Use NSNotificationCenter to send notification to parent and tell him works done. You can add userinfo to identify children among each other.

4) If you don't need to do anything specific after work is done just use dispatch_async and don't hold the reference, it will do its task and die down eventually

I would require more details to give you recommendation about any specific approach. If possible paste your code :)

Comment: +1 for 1) & 4), 3) works, but does not fit, because notifications are unaddressed information flow (broadcast), but a parent is a dedicated object. 2) … no, … really, no.

Comment: @Amin Negm-Awad, the problem is the child object can't set itself to nil. It has to let someone else (e.g. its parents) do that. So I don't see how using dispatch_async can do the trick. Besides the answer, in a way is just repeat what I said. I don't see anything new. I definitely won't use 2/3 (no, no broadcast either)

Comment: Solution 1) (delegation) let you inform the parent, so he can set his ivar. Solution 4) is correct: In your Q you say that the problem is to set the reference to the child to `nil`. So there is nothing else to do. In such a case you do not need a child reference at all. Simply remove it. The block holds the child in its closure. Of course that does not work, if you need the reference for some other reasons (cancelling?)

Comment: Maybe to be clearer with solution 1): Simply having a "callback" instead of proper delegation introduces a dependency from the child to the parent. Having a proper delegation with a protocol removes the dependency to the parent.

Comment: For the 4th solution, I still don't get it. Why would you call dispatch_async {child = nil} in its parents ? What is the point and what is the difference with my releaseChild method ?

Answer (score 1):

If a child object performs an asynchronous operation, it would be most likely that it has a callback block that it calls when the operation is finished, either with success or with failure. And most likely the parent object has created the child, stored a reference, told the child to start the asynchronous operation, and given it the callback block. So that callback would be the perfect place to set some reference to nil.

Comment: Hi, both your solution & @CRD's work, but I will mark his answer as the accepted answer because he told me something I didn't know before. Sorry :$