# How do I manually retain in Swift with ARC?

Tags: swift, automatic-ref-counting, retain, swift3

I'm using Swift 3 with ARC in an iOS app, and I want to manually retain an object.

I tried object.retain() but Xcode says that it's unavailable in ARC mode. Is there an alternative way to do this, to tell Xcode I know what I'm doing?

---

**Long Version:**

I have a LocationTracker class that registers itself as the delegate of a CLLocationManager. When the user's location changes, it updates a static variable named location. Other parts of my code that need the location access this static variable, without having or needing a reference to the LocationTracker instance.

The problem with this design is that delegates aren't retained, so the LocationTracker is deallocated by the time the CLLocationManager sends a message to it, causing a crash.

I would like to manually increment the refcount of the LocationTracker before setting it as a delegate. The object will never be deallocated anyway, since the location should be monitored as long as the app is running.

I found a workaround, which is to have a static variable 'instance' that keeps a reference to the LocationTracker. I consider this design inelegant, since I'm never going to use the 'instance' variable. Can I get rid of it and explicitly increment the refcount?

This question is not a duplicate, as was claimed, since the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489995/manual-object-lifetime-with-arc) is about Objective-C, while this one is about Swift.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manual object lifetime with ARC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489995/manual-object-lifetime-with-arc)

Comment: Not a duplicate. I edited the question to say why.

Comment: I think you'll find a number of the solutions presented are just as applicable to Swift as to Objective-C. Give them a try and you might find a solution suitable for you. HTH

Comment: To the extent they're applicable, they're variations of my static variable idea. In any case, whether the answers are applicable or not, the question is about a different programming language, so the QUESTION is not a duplicate.

Comment: The correct name for your static property is likely `shared`, and it is proper Swift (there are sometimes other names used, but if you need a generic name, use `shared`, not `instance`). There's nothing inelegant about this. This is the standard singleton pattern in Swift, used extensively through stdlib. You should not dive into Unmanaged code (which can do what you're talking about, but is very dangerous and difficult to do correctly, and you'd likely *still* need a static variable to access it) to avoid a standard Swift pattern.

Comment: @RobNapier Oh, unmanaged code isn't something like: unmanaged {object.retain()}?

Comment: I mean Unmanaged: https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/unmanaged. This is a critical escape hatch for some kinds of performance issues and for interoperating with some kinds of ObjC code, but it would be completely inappropriate for the situation you're describing. A static variable is exactly the tool that you should use.

Comment: Thanks. It does seem to be Unamanged.passRetained(object). I don't see anything hacky here or dangerous here, because it matches what I want — make this object live forever. In fact, it's cleaner than a static variable, which can get reassigned, releasing the object and causing a crash when a method is called on the deallocated object.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution turned out to be to re-enable retain() and release():

```
extension NSObjectProtocol {
  /// Same as retain(), which the compiler no longer lets us call:
  @discardableResult
  func retainMe() -> Self {
    _ = Unmanaged.passRetained(self)
    return self
  }

  /// Same as autorelease(), which the compiler no longer lets us call.
  ///
  /// This function does an autorelease() rather than release() to give you more flexibility.
  @discardableResult
  func releaseMe() -> Self {
    _ = Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).autorelease()
    return self
  }
}
```

Comment: This makes sense - but would be interesting to explain why apple removed it. Is there some other approach/method they expect us to use?

Answer (score 9):

This is easily done with the [`withExtendedLifetime(_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/withextendedlifetime(_:_:)-31nv4) function. From the documentation:

> Evaluates a closure while ensuring that the given instance is not destroyed before the closure returns.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of it. I upvoted, but sometimes I have to wait for an async API to call me back, so can't use this.